# Ruby on Rails リンクするホストがないとエラーがでる

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**エラー内容**

Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

---

**/config/environment/development.rb↓**
[image: /config/environment/development.rb]

---

ローカルホストは設定しているのですが。なにが原因でしょうか。

```
host = 'localhost:3000'
```

localhostの部分はいつもブラウザでアクセスしている値にしてもだめでした。なにか根本的な誤りがあるのでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 設定ファイルの内容も、キャプチャ画像ではなくテキストとして投稿してもらった方が親切かなと思います。

Answer (score 1):

**原因不明だが自己解決**

なぜか動きました

**考えられる原因**

・とくになにもしてないので、サーバーの再起動とかそのあたりかもしれません。

それ以外は心当たりがないです。